# Need to calculate sum() base on row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to calculate sum row by row

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  
0   0   1   0   1  
0   1   1   1   1  
1   1   1   1   0  
0   1   0   0   0
```

Desire output

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  SUM  
0   0   1   0   1   2  
0   1   1   1   1   4  
1   1   1   1   0   4  
0   1   0   0   0   1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have error in third row `1 1 1 1 0` is `4` not `3`

Comment: We can't see what part of your code is causing the problem. Did you leave something out of your question?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution will be doing the next query:

```
select s1, s2, s3, s4, s5,isnull(s1,0) + isnull(s2,0) + isnull(s3,0) + isnull(s4,0) + isnull(s5,0) as Total
from table
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f68a/2

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

**Schema**

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE 
(
  s1 int,
  s2 int,
  s3 int,
  s4 int
)

INSERT INTO @table1  VALUES(0,   0,   1,   0)   
INSERT INTO @table1  VALUES(0,   1,   1,   1)
INSERT INTO @table1  VALUES(1,   1,   1,   1)
INSERT INTO @table1  VALUES(0,   1,   1,   0)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4, 
(
    SELECT SUM(TotalCnt) FROM (VALUES (s1), (s2), (s3), (s4)) as t(TotalCnt)
) as [Sum]
FROM @table1
```

**Result**

```
s1  s2  s3  s4  Sum
0   0   1   0   1
0   1   1   1   3
1   1   1   1   4
0   1   1   0   2
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4721)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Use simple addition:

```
SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4, s5,
       [SUM] =  s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5
FROM table;
```

If any column is nullable wrap it with  `COALESCE(sN, 0)`.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418150)**</kbd>

---

To avoid handling `NULL` with `ISNULL/CASE/COALESCE/IIF` you can use `SUM` and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, sub.[sum]
FROM #tab
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(c) 
            FROM (VALUES (s1), (s2), (s3), (s4), (s5)) AS s(c)
            ) AS sub([sum])
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418151)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Simply by `+`.

**Query**

```
SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4, s5,
s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 AS [SUM]
from tblNum;
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd83b/1)**

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
 SELECT  [S1] ,[S2],[S3] ,[S4],[S5], sum(S1+S2+S3+S4+S5) as sum
  FROM TableName
  group by [S1],[S2],[S3] ,[S4],[S5]
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4724)</kbd>